# PCA predicted yield curve moves do not match (closely) realized yield curve moves

Tags: interest-rates, yield-curve, pca

I have a need to set-up a methodology to decompose the x-day yield curve moves into its underlying (3) PCAs. 
Specifically, for an example, to generate the 1-day moves in the EUR-swap yield curve; then explain each day's moves in terms of the 3 PCA's I have generated.

I have found that my PCA-based moves do not correspond to the realized moves; and I am not sure what I might have done wrong in my calculation methodology.
My understanding is that, for a specified yield-curve move (from 1yr to 30yr), the moves across the term can be estimated from

yield(T) = w1 * PCA1(T) + w2 * PCA2(T) + w3 * PCA3(T)

where for example, w1, w2, w3 are the weights for each PCA1, 2 and 3. T is the tenor of the yield-rate, such as 1yr, 2yr... 30y.

My methodology is as follows

1. extract EUR swap yield-rate data April 2016 - April 2019 (from 1yr to
   30yr)
2. extract 1-day move (absolute basis pt change)
3. Extract sample set of 252 days (i.e. from April 2018 - April 2019).
4. Generate the co-variance matrix of the term-structure movement (without removing the mean of the moves)
5. Generate the eigenvalues, and eigenvectors (used python Numpy for this). Use the dominant 3 PCA, which is the parallel, twist and
   bowing movements. See picture of my PCA's below.

[image]

For the 1st day of my realized yield-move (such as 10th April 2019), I calculate the correlation between realized moves and PCA1, PCA2, PCA3.
I obtain the following correlations : w1 = 0.70, w2 = 0.396, w3 - -0.342

With these weights, I should have been able to estimate the realized move, such that 1yr move = w1 * PCA1(1yr-pt) + w2 * PCA2(1yr-pt) + w3 * PCA3(1yr-pt).

**However, my estimation is quite far off. I am not sure if my methodology had anything missing.** I referred to some existing threads, but couldn't find something that addressed my practical calculations.

[Applications of PCA to yield curve analysis](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33381/applications-of-pca-to-yield-curve-analysis)

[Principal component analysis for yield curve](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/principal-component-analysis-for-yield-curve)

[Attributing the change in NII to Shift, Twist and Butterfly](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/10246/attributing-the-change-in-nii-to-shift-twist-and-butterfly)

[image]

Comment: should be almost equal. I assume your PCA is correct. Then decomposition is simply a projection to pca components. I guess you made mistake in this step

Comment: I can post my underlying data, and the derived 3 derived PCA vectors. I don't think they were done incorrectly, as it is a standard python-numpy transform. What I am unsure of, is how to extract the weight de-composition. I had thought it was a simple correlation exercise between the PCA vectors and the realized moves.